# Spring REST service using variable URL

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to develop a RESTful app with Spring. The REST service must be parametrized in a database, I mean, a generic Service that can change the whole URL from a database info doing the same work but pointing to differents URL directions.

I was searching for info related for ages. Does anyone know about useful tutorial?

is it possible to do?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: AFAIK, its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off creating a simple `Servlet` that will listen to a static root url and respond dynamically according to the database value.

```
public class Config {
  public static String restPath = "valueReadFromDB";
}

@WebServlet("/appName")
public class AppServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    if (req.getURI().contains(Config.restPath) {
      // add your logic
    }
  }
}
```

You can call this like so: http://your.host.name/appName/dynamicUrlReadFromDB

Don't blindly attempt to use Spring just because it is cool or fashionable. Sticking to the basics can always yield excellent results and allows for fine-grained control of your application something that Spring cannot always do.